# How to specify the dimension of the simulation box to run molecular dynamics simulation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, simulations, molecular-dynamics, liquid-state, soft-matter

I want to study the physical properties of binary liquids, molecular dynamics simulation using gromacs software is used to simulate the liquids. To set the initial coordinate configuration, how do we determine the size of the simulation box.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the initial box is directly connected to the value of the initial number density. For a constant density simulation, one has to provide the value of density one is interested in. If the simulation is a constant pressure simulation, the number density varies as a function of time. Still, it is useful to start from a *typical* value. Once you know how many particles you want to use ($N$) and the target number density ($\rho$), the required volume is given by $N/\rho$.